# OS Windows Reinstalled, Bitcoin Core bitcoins lost, how do I recover them?

Tags: bitcoin-core, lost-bitcoins

I've lost my bitcoins when I reinstalled OS on my computer.

I still have my receiving address and the password I used to encrypt my Bitcoin Core Wallet.

How do I recover the lost bitcoins? Does anyone know? Thanks!

Comment: do you have backup of your `wallet.dat` file?

Comment: ... or in case you haven't got a backup of the wallet.dat file there is a chance that this file is still on your harddisk. Use Windows' search function.

Comment: I did. And I found it.

I followed instructions and imported the wallet into the app data, but my Bitcoin Core now refuses to start. It gets an error message and does not want to open. How do I make it start? amaclin

Comment: @cassini, also, if that is not possible, can i somehow export the data in a different wallet?

Comment: Please post your debug.log file (or the last few hundred lines of it in case it is too big) and as much information about the error message as possible to pastebin or similar. For manually exporting the private keys to a different wallet you could use [pywallet](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=34028.0). By the way, be careful not to mix up different versions of the wallet.dat file. Backup wallet.dat frequently, and never delete any of these backup files even if you think it is empty or outdated. You may want to retrace your activities at a later stage.